# how to open facebook app on imageview Click event?

Tags: android, android-imageview, facebook-apps

i want to open Facebook app inside my application and it will show on Imageview On click event.
i have referred 10-20 links tried all of them but nothing works for me.
i don want to use Facebook default image button, i want to do it on imageview click event.

i have tried links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
- [Android How to Open Facebook App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097573/android-how-to-open-facebook-app)
- [How to open my facebook page in facebook app from button click of an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049561/how-to-open-my-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-from-button-click-of-an-android-app)
- [How to open Facebook app on user timeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082852/how-to-open-facebook-app-on-user-timeline)
- [Android open facebook page link in facebook app if installed ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143642/android-open-facebook-page-link-in-facebook-app-if-installed)
- [Open Facebook page from Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app?rq=1)

and many more

After trying everything my current code is:

```
 public void shareFacebook() {
    String fullUrl = "https://m.facebook.com";
    try {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setPackage ("com.facebook.katana");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your title text");
        context.startActivity(sharingIntent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(fullUrl));
        context.startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="1975812626048291"/>
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1975812626048291"
    android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="com.facebook.katana.FacebookLoginActivity"
        android:permission="com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION" android:exported="false"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

Dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
```

showing version should be same as recycler view version but putting the same version it is still not working.

```
 jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
```

describe proper way to implement and also i have put that imageview on recyclerview so please whatever u suggest it should be on onBindViewHolder() of recyclerview.

and current  error is:

> Unable to find explicit activity class `{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

i dont know how to describe activity of facebook in manifest ..
and do we need another java activity just to open app inside our application?

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191492/7666442 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810803/open-facebook-page-from-android-app

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have no setType. 
Try this example.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text...");
    sharingIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

open FB App without using facebook SDk
this was my requirement of this question

**reference link**

[Share image and text through Whatsapp or Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook)

```
 Intent FBIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    FBIntent.setType("text/plain");
    FBIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    FBIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
    try {
        context.startActivity(FBIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Facebook have not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );
    }
```

works fine for instagram, twitter also, just need to change the package name.

Answer (score -1):

This method works for me. Check it out.
I took the method from [here](https://gist.github.com/takeshiyako2/8b26bcdd8f2ad4da4fca)

```
protected void OpenFacebookPage(){

     // facebook page id
     String facebookPageID = "dempagumi.inc";

     // URLs
     String facebookUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/" + facebookPageID;

     // URL scheme
     String facebookUrlScheme = "fb://page/" + facebookPageID;

     try {
         // Get Facebook app version
         int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;

         if (versionCode >= 3002850) {
             // For Facebook app version 11.0.0.11.23 (3002850) or higher
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookUrl);
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
         } else {
             // If Facebook app is old
             startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookUrlScheme)));
         }
     } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
         // If Facebook app is not installed, open in browser
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookUrl)));

     }

 }
```